# When upgrading a gas meter, do you need to install/upgrade regulators for natural gas appliances?

Tags: natural-gas, tankless

I live in TX and have Amica as my natural gas provider. I want to replace my tank water heaters with a tankless unit. According to the Amica tech, I will need an upgraded gas meter which would increase my home's gas line from 0.25 to 2 PSI.

He also said once this happens, I'll need to make sure I have regulators in place at each of my gas appliances to make sure they don't get damaged from having too high pressure gas coming into them.

I can't seem to find any other information that mentions this. No YouTube videos besides people replacing bad regulators and no posts anywhere. Am I missing something? Do I need to install regulators before these appliances so they don't get overwhelmed with the increased gas pressure?

My gas appliances are my kitchen stove, furnace, and fireplace as well as the two water heater tanks to be removed soon for the tankless unit.

Comment: I suspect what you need is a 2psi meter, then a T, with one pipe to the heater and another to a 0.25psi regulator and on to your existing appliances. Not an answer because I'm not an expert in natural gas systems or the regulations in your area, but it's the logical way to do it from my perspective of inert gases.

Comment: I agree Chris H, in my area we cannot get 2 psi in a residence only the standard 3/4 psi because of the additional regulators inside the home that are needed. My tank less water heater still works but the max temp with a full flow is only ~128-134. I would like it hotter but would not trade it for anything, way cheaper to run and I can set it at 102 and fill my hot tub and jump right in.

Comment: I don't intend to add a new line from the meter. That would require way too much pipe, when I can simply run a line from my attic to the garage, needing only 10 feet of pipe or so